# Can you pump while being part of a team?

Tags: risus

One of the advanced options for Risus are the rules for Pumps (R:TARPG p. 4), allowing your to take a hit in order to roll more dice. But can you do this while part of a team (R:TARPG p. 3)? I understand that only the sixes still count and when doing this you might not want to be your team's volunteer in case your team loses and take damage, but can you pump when not rolling normally?

Answer (score 4):

Like @Chuk said, Risus doesn't prohibit the use of Pumps in teams. One could interpret the following:

> Pumps are legal for any kind of Cliché roll, provided the GM agrees that  “pushing it” fits the action involved. (R:TARPG p.4)

to allow this behavior.

As you said, it wouldn't be the most helpful tactic if you were a helper, but as a leader it could help, while making you easier to defeat, as pumping does, by reducing your cliché.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't say you can't in the rules or in the Companion. I'd allow it. Like you say though, it might not help that much.